# How can I wait for a promise to return in a <script> tag in raw HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a div that fills with the view count of the page. What I want to is make a request to my server to get the view count and then render that on the page. However, since the page loads before the request responds, the text shown is `[Object Promise]`.
The code in my <script> tag is:

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("viewcount").innerHTML = await fetch("https://mywebsite.com/peripherals/viewcount")
                                                     .then(function (response) {
                                                         return response.json();
                                                     }).then(function (json) {
                                                         return json.count
                                                     }).catch(function (error) {
                                                         console.log("Error: " + error);
                                                     });
</script>
```

How can I delay the rendering of the viewcount until a response is returned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the text shown is [Object Promise]

This would happen if you would not use `await`.

When you add `await`, you'll get an error, because it can only be used (at the time of writing) within an `async` function, so wrap it:

```
(async function () {
    document.getElementById("viewcount").innerHTML = await fetch(/* ...etc */);
})();
```

You could use `await` all the way:

```
(async function () {
    try {
        const response = await fetch("https://mywebsite.com/peripherals/viewcount");
        const {count} = await response.json();
        document.getElementById("viewcount").innerHTML = count;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error: " + error);
    }
})();
```